# Filling out Fillable PDF From Excel Data

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have an Excel sheet with customer information (Name, Address, Account Number, etc.) and have a fillable PDF that I need to complete and save for each customer. How can I map the data from Excel into the fields in the fillable PDF? Doing some research on it, it looks like using VBA might be an option but I'm not real well versed in it. I did export the fillable PDF to XML and then added it as a source in Excel to try to map the data but it didn't have any fields to map.

Comment: I did this by creating TextFields within the pdf and naming them.  You can then set the Textfield to a value in a cell in excel

Comment: Would you happen to have an example of that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link](https://www.excel-first.com/use-excel-to-populate-pdf-form-fields/) that might help. There are some videos and sample files on that website that can help as well.

The high level steps from that website are as follows:

1. Prepare the Excel structure for export.
2. Extract the XML structure of the PDF form. You can use [Adobe Acrobat Pro](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/acrobat-pro.html) (It can be done without the need to have a licensed Acrobat Pro version, but it requires at least a trial of Acrobat PRO installed, even if you never purchase a license.), [FoxitReader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/forms.php), [PDF XChange Viewer](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/downloads), etc.
3. Map the XML file to the Excel sheet.
4. Use the XML file to fill out the PDF form.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I initially tried but when I added the XML file into Excel as the source, it didn't have any of the mapping fields.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how I accomplished this, not positive if it will work for you.  Some things to note:

I use Foxitpdf and wanted to print to pdf to create new pdf's from a template.

```
Sub CreateDrawings()

Dim phApp As PhantomPDF.Application
Set phApp = CreateObject("PhantomPDF.Application")
Dim phCreator As PhantomPDF.Creator
Set phCreator = phApp.Creator

Dim PDFTemplateFile, NewPDFName, SavePDFFldr, Desc As String
Dim CustRow, LastRow As Long

SavePDFFldr = Sheet2.Range("D47").Value           ' Or set this to an exact directory

CreateObject("WScript.Network").SetDefaultPrinter "Microsoft Print to PDF"

LastRow = Sheet2.Range("A999").End(xlUp).Row
PDFTemplateFile1 = Sheet4.Range("E3").Value  'or set this to the exact pdf file directory.

Dim phFormDoc As PhantomPDF.Document
Set phFormDoc = phApp.OpenDocument(PDFTemplateFile1, "", True, True)
    
    D1 = .Range("M" & CustRow).Value & "''"
    D2 = .Range("AD" & CustRow).Value               
    D3 = .Range("AK" & CustRow).Value & " lbs"      
    D4 = .Range("D" & CustRow).Value              
    D5 = .Range("Z" & CustRow).Value & "''"           
    D6 = .Range("AC" & CustRow).Value & "''"        
    D7 = .Range("AA" & CustRow).Value & "''"      
    D8 = .Range("V" & CustRow).Value & "''"        

' D1-D8 are set prior to setting pdf fields to the values to make the code cleaner to look at
    
    Call phFormDoc.SetFieldValue("Size", CStr(D1))
    Call phFormDoc.SetFieldValue("Material", CStr(D2))
    Call phFormDoc.SetFieldValue("Weight", CStr(D3))
    Call phFormDoc.SetFieldValue("Description", CStr(D4))
    Call phFormDoc.SetFieldValue("Inlet", CStr(D5))
    Call phFormDoc.SetFieldValue("Length", CStr(D6))
    Call phFormDoc.SetFieldValue("Outlet", CStr(D7))
    Call phFormDoc.SetFieldValue("MajorDiameter", CStr(D8))

    Description = D4                                    ' whatever dimension is the description of the element
    
Call phFormDoc.Export(SavePDFFldr & "\" & Description & ".pdf")
    
Call phApp.CloseDocument(phFormDoc, False)

Next CustRow

Call phApp.Exit

End With
```

I'm not positive what you use for your pdf application but with Foxit, it wasn't too difficult.

I've left out much of the looping and If statements since they'll just add irrelevant info.

End Sub

Comment: Great, thank you. I'm trying to follow along with a YouTube video and just have some of the basic code to open the template but I'm getting a compile error when running it. Cell B26 is the path to my template, c:\backup\template.PDF.

`Sub CreatePDFForms()
Dim PDFTemplateFile, NewPDFName, SavePDFFolder, CustomerName As String
Dim CustRow, LastRow As Long
With Sheet1
LastRow = .Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row
PDFTemplateFile = .Range("B26").Value 'Template File Name
SavePDFFolder = .Range("B27").Value 'Save Location
OpenURL "" & PDFTemplateFile & ""

End With
End Sub`

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to layout the code correctly. I'm also using Foxit Reader. On your code, is Size, Material, Weight, etc. fieldnames arein the PDF document and then you're assigning those to the cells in Excel?

Comment: @pantherhawk yes those are the textfield names within the pdf.  The code ```Call phFormDoc.SetFieldValue("Size", CStr(D1))``` is just setting the value of the text field to that specified "D1" value that was set a few lines above.  ```CStr(D1)``` is only making sure that the value is converted to a string prior to transferring to the pdf.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anything in that code that is specific to the filename of the PDF you're using or should I be able to use that and just change some of the fieldnames and where those cells are?

Comment: The ```SavePDFFldr``` and ```PDFTemplateFile1``` are specifically named to folders/files on my computer.  You would just need to name those correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have it working but have one last question. In my PDF form, I have 2 checkboxes, firsttime and secondtime. In Excel column I, there is either a 1 or a 2. How would I write an IF statement to say if column I = 1 then sendkeys "{spacebar}" else sendkeys "{tab}"? I would then do the same thing for the secondtime checkbox to look for a 2 in column I.